# Почему toggle работает не правильно

Tags: javascript

Вопрос из разряда мозг вырубился...
Почему `toggle` работает не правильно, как исправить?

```
let btn = document.querySelector('.modal-open')
btn.addEventListener('click',()=>{
    // открывает модалку
    modal.classList.toggle('mmo')
        // слушатель на esc
        document.addEventListener('keydown',e => {
            if(e.code === 'Escape'){
                modal.classList.toggle('mmo')
            }
        },{once:true})
        //слушатель на кнопку внутри modal
        close.addEventListener('click',e => {
            modal.classList.toggle('mmo')
        },{once:true})
})
```

Comment: подумайте, сколько слушателей Вы навешиваете...

Comment: @StrangerintheQ один из них не запускается это понятно но как исправить говорю же мозг в минус

Comment: Отформатируйте код нормально и дайте индексируемый заголовок

Comment: @Armen повесьте их один раз, на одном уровне вложенности

Comment: @StrangerintheQ спасибо за понимание)

Comment: @Armen вам что-то в моём ответе непонятно? Могу ответить, если у вас есть вопросы

Comment: @МихаилКамахин все понятно просто в решении слушатели остаются зачем? если они нужны только когда есть модалка сам кинул ответ на мой вопрос

Comment: @Armen ну это если вы уже хотите напишите удаление слушателей: если открыта модалка, добавить слушатель события на keydown, когда модалка закрыта удалить слушатель события

Comment: @МихаилКамахин и спасибо за такой проработанный ответ

Comment: @МихаилКамахин в вашем решении слушатели добавляются изначально не пойму как можно их удалить если событие не наступило может модалка вообще не откроется

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const modal = document.querySelector('.modal');
const modalOpen = document.querySelector('.modal-open');
const modalClose = document.querySelector('.modal-close');

modalOpen.addEventListener('click', () => {
  modal.classList.add('active');
});

modalClose.addEventListener('click', () => {
  modal.classList.remove('active');
});

document.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
  if (e.code === 'Escape') {
    modal.classList.remove('active')
  }
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@400;600;700;800;900&display=swap');
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  z-index: 1;
  color: white;
  transform: scale(0);
  transition: transform 0.2s linear;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.modal-close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 2px;
  top: 2px;
  padding: 5px;
  color: var(--firstColor);
  border: 2px solid var(--firstColor);
  background-color: var(--secondColor);
}

.modal-open {
  color: var(--secondColor);
  border: 2px solid var(--secondColor);
  background-color: var(--firstColor);
  padding: 5px;
}

.modal-close,
.modal-open {
  --firstColor: white;
  --secondColor: black;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  transition-property: color, background-color, border-color;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
}

.modal-close:hover,
.modal-open:hover {
  --firstColor: black;
  --secondColor: white;
}

.modal-body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.modal-content {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 40px;
}

.modal.active {
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<div class="modal-open">Открыть</div>
<div class="modal">
  <div class="modal-close">Закрыть</div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="modal-content">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos perspiciatis inventore iste accusantium adipisci labore tempore ut voluptatum eos debitis fuga, sequi doloribus culpa in odit sint dolor animi beatae eius! Suscipit similique magnam dolores
      architecto aspernatur ipsam nam ratione officiis, labore id eligendi ea corrupti at doloribus saepe, mollitia dignissimos itaque. Dolore soluta quos commodi corrupti nobis facilis voluptates magnam atque, neque delectus pariatur natus nostrum qui
      molestiae mollitia animi explicabo cum non accusantium, quod minus minima porro dolorum blanditiis? Temporibus amet saepe sequi aliquid sit, sunt, odit est, culpa fugit vitae delectus magnam hic molestiae quidem expedita quos.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Как удалить слушатели:

```js
const modal = document.querySelector('.modal');
const modalOpen = document.querySelector('.modal-open');
const modalClose = document.querySelector('.modal-close');

modalOpen.addEventListener('click', () => {
  modal.classList.add('active');
  document.addEventListener('keydown', removeModalEscape);
});

modalClose.addEventListener('click', () => {
  modal.classList.remove('active');
  document.removeEventListener('keydown', removeModalEscape);
});

function removeModalEscape(e) {
  if (e.code === 'Escape') {
    modal.classList.remove('active');
    document.removeEventListener('keydown', removeModalEscape);
  }
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@400;600;700;800;900&display=swap');
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  z-index: 1;
  color: white;
  transform: scale(0);
  transition: transform 0.2s linear;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.modal-close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 2px;
  top: 2px;
  padding: 5px;
  color: var(--firstColor);
  border: 2px solid var(--firstColor);
  background-color: var(--secondColor);
}

.modal-open {
  color: var(--secondColor);
  border: 2px solid var(--secondColor);
  background-color: var(--firstColor);
  padding: 5px;
}

.modal-close,
.modal-open {
  --firstColor: white;
  --secondColor: black;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  transition-property: color, background-color, border-color;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
}

.modal-close:hover,
.modal-open:hover {
  --firstColor: black;
  --secondColor: white;
}

.modal-body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.modal-content {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 40px;
}

.modal.active {
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<div class="modal-open">Открыть</div>
<div class="modal">
  <div class="modal-close">Закрыть</div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="modal-content">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos perspiciatis inventore iste accusantium adipisci labore tempore ut voluptatum eos debitis fuga, sequi doloribus culpa in odit sint dolor animi beatae eius! Suscipit similique magnam dolores
      architecto aspernatur ipsam nam ratione officiis, labore id eligendi ea corrupti at doloribus saepe, mollitia dignissimos itaque. Dolore soluta quos commodi corrupti nobis facilis voluptates magnam atque, neque delectus pariatur natus nostrum qui
      molestiae mollitia animi explicabo cum non accusantium, quod minus minima porro dolorum blanditiis? Temporibus amet saepe sequi aliquid sit, sunt, odit est, culpa fugit vitae delectus magnam hic molestiae quidem expedita quos.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`btn.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
    bool = true
    toggle()
    bool = false
    document.addEventListener('keydown',toggle)
    close.addEventListener('click',toggle)
    
})

function toggle(){
    if(event.target.classList.value == 'close' || event.code == 'Escape'){
        document.removeEventListener('keydown',toggle)
        close.removeEventListener('click',toggle)
    }

    if(bool || event.code == 'Escape' || event.target.classList.value == 'close'){
        modal.classList.toggle('mmo')
    }   
}`